# Adding items in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, int, sum

I am having problem on how to add items in my dictionary.

```
        int y = 0;
        foreach (var entry in fun)
        {
                entry.Value += entry.Value;
                y = entry.Value;
        }
```

This doesn't work. I want to have a sum of all items in my dictionary:

```
var fun = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

For example, the string is `Hello fun fun`, so dictinary will show Hello: 1, Fun: 2, and sum is 3. And I want that 3 to be counted.

Comment: So you want to know the number of elements in your dictionary or the sum of the integer values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more elegant LINQ solutions, but this should do the trick:

```
    int y = 0;
    foreach (var entry in fun)
    {
            y += entry.Value;
    }
```

As mentioned by @Rotem in the comments it's as easy as:

```
fun.Values.Sum()
```

Comment: The more elegant LINQ solution being: `fun.Values.Sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to do.

```
 foreach (var entry in fun)
        {

                y = y + entry.Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to modify Value property of KeyValuePair type, which is read-only.

Better use LINQ:

```
fun.Aggregate(0, (sum, keyValue) => sum + keyValue.Value);
```